# Laravel Passport API error in create token

Tags: php, laravel, api

Although project work fine in local, when deploy on server found error.
laravel 7
php version 7.4.13

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'Parser' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in file /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Configuration.php on line 22

[image: ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'Parser' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in file /var/www/html/laravel/vendor/lcobucci/jwt/src/Configuration.php on line 22]

```
public function verifyOtp(Request $request)
{
    $phoneno = $request->input('loginId');
    $enteredOtp = $request->input('password');

    $loginData = [
        'login_id' => $phoneno,
        'password' => $enteredOtp
    ];

    // dd($loginData);
    if (!auth()->attempt($loginData)) {
        return response([
            'message' => 'OTP incorrect!',
            'status'=>0
        ]);
    } else {
        // dd("Here");
         $accessToken = auth()->user()->createToken('authToken')->accessToken;
         return response([
                'user' =>auth()->user(),
                'access_token' =>$accessToken,
                'message'=>"Successfully login",
                'status'=>1
        ]);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what version of Laravel are you using, what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @aungsoeoo did you get a solution for this error?

Answer (score 2):

You would need PHP 7.4+ to use the code base you currently have. The version of the package that the error is coming from uses features from PHP 7.4.

Comment: my current  PHP version is 7.4.13 and it still error.

Comment: @aungsoeoo that is not the version being used when you get that error ... that error is from having a version of PHP lower than 7.4

Comment: If you're using Laravel Forge, then you can read on how to change it here: https://laravel-forge-menubar.com/articles/update-phpversion-laravel-forge . I had the newer version installed, but had forgotten to switch the PHP-version for the application.